# Real Linear vs. Complex Linear

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

I recently started a new math course and got hung up on a particular problem from the book "Linear Algebra Done Wrong". Specifically, problem 1.3.6 (c). I am an engineer, and I believe I simply lack terminology/definition to solve the problem. Again, it is part (c) of the problem:

The set $\mathbb C$ of complex numbers can be canonically identied with the space $\mathbb R^2$
by treating each ($z = x + iy$) of $\mathbb C$ as a column $(x , y)^T$ of $\mathbb R^2$.

Define $T(x+iy) = 2x-y+i(x-3y)$. Show that this transformation is not
a linear transformation in the complex vectors space $\mathbb C$, but if we treat $\mathbb C$ as the real vector space $\mathbb R^2$ then it is a linear transformation there (i.e. that $T$ is a real linear but not a complex linear transformation). Find the matrix of the real liner transformation $T$.

It appears to me that:

$T(au+bv) = aT(u)+bT(v)$

I can't see why it is not linear on $\mathbb C$ but it is on $\mathbb R^2$. However, I recognize that I don't understand how this changes the outcome. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There are some symbols that you used in the definition that aren't being rendered properly (on my computer, at least): what is "" supposed to be?

Comment: Write out, say, $u=p+qi, v=r+si$, and let $a$ and $b$ be real scalars. You can just show directly that the $\mathbb R$-linearity works out. For showing that complex linearity doesn't, just pick specific vectors and complex scalars; almost anything will work as a counterexample.

Comment: Apart from this question, I would recommend you not to read that book. It uses very different from standard linear algebra book. Since you are an engineer, it will not be very helpful to you. I recommend Linear algebra / Kenneth Hoffman, Ray Kunze or Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler

Comment: I really like the book "Linear Algebra" by Lay. It was more elementary and appropriate for applied students. I'm not saying that it is weak, it just does not abstract things out of r2/r3 as often. It also does not start in vector spaces. I am however at the mercy of my Professor here. Can someone provide a counterexample? I must be missing the point here. Best.

Comment: If a transformation is Complex-linear, then it commutes with i i.e. T(ix) = iT(x)

Comment: Wow, that simple? Thanks so much. I believe I tend to overthink things. Hopefully I will get through this course well.

Answer (score 9):

For $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$T(v_1 + v_2) = T(x_1 + x_2 + i(y_1 + y_2)) = ... = T(v_1) + T(v_2)$

(This is easy to check)

Similarly, $T(\alpha v) = T(\alpha x + i \alpha y) = ... =\alpha T(v)$ is also easy to check.

This proves the linearity of T when $\mathbb{C}$ is viewed as $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Calculating Matrix**:

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    1
\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    1
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    -1\\
    -3
\end{bmatrix}$

Matrix of T is $\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1\\
    1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$

---

Now for $\mathbb{C}$ as complex plane:

Take $\alpha = a + ib, v = = x + iy$

$T(\alpha v) = T(ax-by + i(ay + bx)) \neq \alpha T(v) $

Very easy to check. Use the definition of T

Hence, T is not Complex linear

Answer (score 1):

As another way of looking at this, you may remember $\mathbb{R}$ linear maps only having linear factors of what you're putting in? This also applies in the complex setting, but we also can't have complex conjugation showing up (messes up pulling out constants). In your example, we easily see that (noting $x = (z + \bar z)/2$ and $ y = ( z - \bar z)/2i$)).
$$ T(z) = z + \bar z - \frac{z - \bar z}{2i} + i \left (\frac{z + \bar z }{2} - 3 \frac{z - \bar z}{2i} \right ) =\left( \frac{-1+5i}{2} \right )z + \left (\frac{1 + 5i}{2} \right) \bar z$$ 
Since $\bar z$ shows up we see this will never allow $T( az) = a T(z)$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}$.